# How to make exe run as scheduled task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scheduled-tasks, exe

I created a WinForm project in c# and added a code file called Loader.cs.  In that file I have a method called LoadData().  I deleted the default "Form1" from the project changed the logic in the Main() to run the LoadData() method.  This all works when run in my VS2008 IDE.  I then built as Release and moved the resulting .exe to a different machine and set up a Scheduled Task with the trigger every hour and the action pointing to the .exe with /Auto as an argument.  The task does nothing, just sits running and is not doing any of the processing.  I have to eventually end the task.  Same if run manually.  If I double click the exe from the folder where it's located it does nothing.  How can I get this exe to run as Scheduled Task or even just run independently?

In Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Loader lc = new Loader();
        lc.LoadData();
    }
}
```

And in the Loader.cs file:

```
    public void LoadData()
{
   // ...processing
}
```

Comment: I would try putting try { } catch { } in your main and writing the Exception (if one occurs to disk for examination)

Comment: Well if it fails on the 2nd machine when run *normally*, this has nothing to do with it being a scheduled task.  Look in the event log, add some diagnostic logging after ensuring your not swallowing any exceptions in your code.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: what is `Loader` is that the actual task scheduler..? if it is then you need to remove that code and just point the task scheduler to the .exe and let it invoke your winforms .exe appliation

Comment: Added logging in the Main and its the WCF endpoint that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. B, not sure how to give you credit here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try putting try { } catch { } in your main and examining the Exception.